# Create an interactive custom tooltip for chartjs

Tags: javascript, hover, chart.js, tooltip, interactive

I'm using `chartjs 2.8` and I've created some custom html tooltip for it, now i need to make that `tooltip` interactive ( aka - hoverable, clickable etc...)

The problem is that chartjs only shows the tooltip while I hover over the point of data i want to see in the tooltip, once i hover outside to get in the tooltip it disappears.

I've tried checking chartjs docs for some options solution for that but couldn't find anything helpful\working.

I've been thinking to play with my `customTooltip function` so it will only disappear once `tooltipModel.opacity===0` and the mouse is out of the tooltip, but I'm having some difficulties here

```
this.tooltip = $('<div/>').addClass('chartjs-tooltip')[0];
        document.body.appendChild(this.tooltip);

        return new Chart($chart, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: datasets,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
            },
            options: Object.assign({}, options, {
                tooltips: {
                    // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
                    enabled: false,

                    custom: (tooltipModel) => {
                        // Hide if no tooltips
                        if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                            $(this.tooltip).empty().removeClass('visible');
                            return;
                        } else {
                            $(this.tooltip).addClass('visible');
                        }

                        // Set caret Position
                        this.tooltip.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                        if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                            this.tooltip.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
                        } else {
                            this.tooltip.classList.add('no-transform');
                        }

                        function getBody(bodyItem) {
                            return bodyItem.lines;
                        }

                        // Set Text
                        if ( empty_datapoint ) {
                            if (tooltipModel.body) {
                                this.tooltip.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                                let titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                                let bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                                let innerHtml = '<thead>';

                                titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                                });
                                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                                bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                                    let colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                                    let style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor + ';';
                                    let span = '<span class="color-box" style="' + style + '"></span>';
                                    innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                                });
                                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                                let tableRoot = this.tooltip.querySelector('table');
                                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                                this.tooltip.addStyles({
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
                                    borderRadius: '6px',
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    fontFamily: tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily,
                                    fontSize: tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px',
                                    fontStyle: tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle,
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            let $tooltip = this.customTooltip(tooltipModel.dataPoints);
                            $('.chartjs-tooltip').html($tooltip);
                            tooltipModel.caretX += -150;
                        }

                        // `this` will be the overall tooltip
                        let position = this.chart.$el.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                        // Display, position, and set styles for font
                        this.tooltip.addStyles({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            left: position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px',
                            top: position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px',
                            padding: tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px',
                            zIndex: 9999999999,
                            // pointerEvents: 'none'; // pretty sure we'll want pointer event in the future
                        });
                    }
                }
            }),
        });
```

Comment: I have got close to what you want by putting an `onMouseLeave` event handler on the tooltip to hide it when the mouse leaves the tooltip instead of the point.

Comment: I ignore the mouse leaving the point like this:

`if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
return;
}`

This keeps the tooltip visible whilst the user interacts with it. Unfortunately, if the mouse moves off the chart point without ever entering the tooltip, then the tooltip stays visible.

Comment: Tnx for the reply, i've already found a solution.
I'm listening to - 
mouse leaving the element containing the tooltip, it's not attached to the body rather to the container of the chart
on opacity change to 0 i set a timeout of 200ms to check for mouse hover on the tooltip and if there is none i hide it
works great so far

Answer (score 1):

```
    let tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

    if (!tooltipEl) {
      tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
      tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
      tooltipEl.innerHTML = `<table></table>`;
      document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);

      tooltipEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
      });
      tooltipEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
      });
```

You can also control tooltip visibility in afterEvent hook.

```
    plugins: [
      {
        id: 'turnOffTooltipPlugin',
        afterEvent(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
          const { event } = args;

          if (event.native.type === 'mouseout') {
            let tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

           if (tooltipEl) {
             tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
           }
        }
      }
     ]
```